# igraph 0.7.1 failing to install on R 3.1.0

Tags: r, osx-mavericks, igraph

I am trying to install igraph 0.7.1 on a macbook pro with mavericks. I have installed R 3.1.0 using macports and keep getting the following warnings / errors when installing igraph using install.packages("igraph"):

```
/usr/bin/clang -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/opt/local/include   -DUSING_R -I. -Ics -Iglpk -Iglpk/amd -Iglpk/colamd -Iplfit -pipe -Os -flax-vector-conversions -arch x86_64 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -pipe -Os -flax-vector-conversions -arch x86_64 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -DNDEBUG -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"@VERSION@\" -DINTERNAL_ARPACK -DIGRAPH_THREAD_LOCAL=/**/ -fPIC  -pipe -Os -flax-vector-conversions -arch x86_64  -c colamd.c -o colamd.o

colamd.c:1979:27: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'sqrt' with type 'double (double)'
        dense_row_count = DENSE_DEGREE (knobs [COLAMD_DENSE_ROW], n_col) ;
                          ^
colamd.c:792:33: note: expanded from macro 'DENSE_DEGREE'
        ((Int) MAX (16.0, (alpha) * sqrt ((double) (n))))
                                    ^
colamd.c:794:27: note: expanded from macro 'MAX'
         #define MAX(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
                                   ^
colamd.c:1979:27: note: please include the header <math.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'sqrt'
colamd.c:792:33: note: expanded from macro 'DENSE_DEGREE'
         ((Int) MAX (16.0, (alpha) * sqrt ((double) (n))))
                                     ^
colamd.c:794:27: note: expanded from macro 'MAX'
          #define MAX(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
                                    ^

1 warning generated.
```

The install then completes with the following error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'igraph', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
  dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/igraph/libs/igraph.so, 10): Symbol not found: _colamd_printf
  Referenced from: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/igraph/libs/igraph.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/igraph/libs/igraph.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/igraph’
```

I have Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) installed on my machine. I would be very grateful for some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: R authors do not test R or packages with macports, so unless you have a particular reason for using it, I suggest using the original R installer.

Comment: I didn't realise. Thanks. Will try that.

Comment: Thanks it works now - using igraph 0.70.

Comment: I had the same error in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I was using Mavericks OS X on an Apple MacBook Pro machine. I installed the binary from the R project rather than Macports and it worked.